# CMake: find Qt packages when two Qt versions are installed

Tags: qt, cmake

On my computer (Ubuntu-Gnome) are two Qt-versions installed. One with the package manager (5.x) and one manually to */opt/Qt* (5.9).

For one project I need to use the */opt/Qt*-installation with CMake. But `find_package(Qt5Core 5.9 COMPONENTS CORE REQUIRED)` does not find the correct installation:

```
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt5Core" that is
  compatible with requested version "5.9".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake, version: 5.7.1
```

I tried to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to add a search path to CMake with all variants of paths but it does not work at all.

How can I correctly set the search path to the second installation at */opt/Qt/*?

---

Updates in order to @Florian input

This works:

```
find_package(
   Qt5Core 5.9
   COMPONENTS
      Core
   REQUIRED
)
```

together with

```
cmake -DQt5_DIR:PATH=/opt/Qt/5.9.2/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Core
```

but in this case I found only QT5Core. With that it seems to work for all components as well:

```
find_package(
   Qt5 5.9
   COMPONENTS
      Core
   REQUIRED
)
```

together with

```
cmake -DQt5_DIR:PATH=/opt/Qt/5.9.2/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5
```

---

2nd Edit

To avoid to always put the the full path in the call I add this to the my *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
set(QT_INSTALL_PATH /opt/Qt)
file( GLOB_RECURSE sres ${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/*/Qt5Config.cmake )
get_filename_component( Qt5_DIR ${sres} DIRECTORY )
```

Afterwards this works fine:

```
find_package(
   Qt5 5.9
   COMPONENTS
      Core
      Network
   REQUIRED
)
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `cmake -DQt5Core_DIR:PATH=/opt/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Core ..`?

Comment: @Florian Yes - but it does not work. Now I try generate a list of all paths to pass them to `find_package`. I'm wondering that there is no way to say: This is the base folder of Qt. Search here recursively.

Comment: Strange. You could try the other way around by ignoring the "unwanted" path: `cmake -DCMAKE_IGNORE_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `cmake -DQt5_DIR:PATH=/opt/Qt5/5.9.2/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5`

[Documentation](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/25864/)