# Building Supercollider from source, wrong version of qt.

Tags: qt, cmake, supercollider

I have Linux Mint 19, and i really want to install SuperCollider. I cant do it by apt-get, because there is old version which do not support SuperDirt. I need to build it from source. I use this guide:
https://github.com/supercollider/supercollider/wiki/Installing-SuperCollider-from-source-on-Ubuntu
Problem is with cmake:

```
cmake -qt=qt5.11 -DSC_EC=ON -DSC_EL=OFF -DSC_WII=OFF -DSC_IDE=ON ..
-- SuperCollider Version: 3.10.0-beta2
-- Building from branch develop, commit hash is f543f53
-- Build type defaulting to "RelWithDebInfo"
-- Compiling with Qt GUI
-- building boost libraries manually
-- using bundled libyaml-cpp
-- HIDAPI components:
--     linux hidraw
-- libudev stable: 1
-- Found UDev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so
--    include: /usr/include
--     hidapi_parser
-- Building with HID support
-- Using fftw3f
-- Found jack: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so
-- Audio API: jack
-- Found GNU Readline version 6.3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so
CMake Error at QtCollider/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt5" that is compatible
  with requested version "5.7".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake, version: 5.5.1

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lang/CMakeLists.txt:155 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/nedlo/programming/supcol/bsource/supercollider/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

So i need at least qt5.7, but i have qt5.5.1 I dont know how to update qt. I installed Qt Creator 5.11, but how do i "show" cmake that i should use qt5.11, if it automatically checks path to /usr/lib/.../qt5 which has qt5.5.1? What am i supposed to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake: find Qt packages then two Qt versions are installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003854/cmake-find-qt-packages-then-two-qt-versions-are-installed)

Comment: Ok, so now i found qt511 in /opt/lib but where do i find qt511.cmake file i should include into path

Comment: Just search it under `/opt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the directory in your Qt installation that contains bin, lib, include, etc. It typically looks something like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64 ...
```